# Showing loader indicator

Tags: javascript, get, loader

I have a page linking to another separated page on the server. I would like to present a loader that finishes exactly when the second page is fully loaded. I dont use AJAX to call the second page, but a simple GET action. Is there a way to control that?

an example would be at: http://m.elal.co.il when you click on one of the buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way here is to preload page with ajax and then push all content of second page to body tag of this page.

Comment: That's why I asked the question, since Im not using ajax